# Mongo find by id in Phoenix

Tags: phoenix-framework

When trying to find by id I don't get a result using the mongodb driver that comes with Phoenix.

The readme in the mongodb package has the following examples

```
Mongo.find(MongoPool, "test-collection", %{}, limit: 20)
Mongo.find(MongoPool, "test-collection", %{"field" => %{"$gt" => 0}}, limit: 20, sort: %{"field" => 1})
```

but when I try like the following I don't get any results.

```
cursor = Mongo.find(AppName.Repo.Pool, "test-collection", %{"_id" => "1df66b12302b812298308dba"})
Enum.to_list(cursor)
```

Get [] empty list.

Do I need to convert the id to something first?

I would like to not have to use Ecto all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the following code that works to convert a string mongo document id to what can be plugged into a mongodb _id parameter

```
def objectid(id) do
    {_, idbin} = Base.decode16(id, case: :mixed)
    %BSON.ObjectId{value: idbin}
end
```